# Input pattern in files upload for other types

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I know how to filter the types of uploaded files for images and pdf but do not know how to manage other types like .dwg, .obj and so on....

My pattern is: image/*,application/pdf,application/obj,application/dwg

The fact is that it does not work when I select a file with the extension .dwg or .obj.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At least I could find a website where it's published a great set of mime types.

For those that need it: [enter link description here](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)

Hope this help.